# Minhag Hebrew Pronunciation each letter

Tags: minhag, hebrew, aleph-bet-letters

Is the pronunciation of the Hebrew letters a minhag or is the pronunciation of each individual letter each an individual minhag itself?

For example would the pronunciation of the letter dalet be one minhag and the pronunciation of tav be another individual minhag OR would the pronunciation for each letter be bagged into one single minhag?

Comment: Why should it make a difference?

Comment: If it helps, I know some people who pronounce some letters ashkenazi minhag, and some Sephardi minhag